How to create sliding text animation
I'm trying to create this transition like in the video. On hover I want the text to slide in from right. I tried to create it but its not sliding through the icons instead behind the icons.

Here is my code. Please any help would be appreciated.


body {
  margin: 3em;
}

.utility-nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}

.utility-nav-link {
  margin-left: 18px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.utility-nav-link span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transform: translate(0px);
}

.utility-nav-link:hover {
  width: 35px;
  transform: translateX(-20px);
}

.utility-nav-link:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.utility-nav-icon {
  background: #888;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
<div class="utility-nav-links">

  <a class="utility-nav-link" href="">
    <img class="utility-nav-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/40" alt="">
    <span>search</span>
  </a>
  
  <a class="utility-nav-link" href="">
    <img class="utility-nav-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/42" alt="">
    <span>info</span>
  </a>
  
  <a class="utility-nav-link" href="">
    <img class="utility-nav-icon" src="https://picsum.photos/44" alt="">
    <span>My Housing</span>
  </a>

</div>




Please make your code into a runnable snippet - and test to make sure it demonstrates the problem. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also please explain where jquery comes into this, or remove the tag, and include the tag of whatever pre-processor you are using.

Consider making the spans relative rather than absolute and try transitioning their width rather than absolute and opacity 0.

You can do this without messing about with positioning. Just transition the width of your text span on hover, between zero and the intrinsic width of the text.
The first catch is that you can’t smoothly transition the width (or height) of an element between zero and auto. The spec excluded it for performance reasons. In future, we may be able to. But for now, you have to transition between two specific widths. That’s where script comes in handy ... from script you can determine the intrinsic width of the element (using its scrollWidth property), then assign this value to a CSS property (variable) which you then refer to in your style rules.
/* in script, add a property to each span whose value is its intrinsic width */

document.querySelectorAll('.utility-nav-links > a > span').forEach(s => {
  s.style.setProperty('--intrinsicWidth', s.scrollWidth + 'px')
})

/* in css, on hover, set the span width to the value of the property */ 

.utility-nav-links > a > span {
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.utility-nav-links > a:hover > span {
  width: var(--intrinsicWidth);
}

The second catch is that because it contains a space, the label “My Housing” will wrap when its width is narrower than its intrinsic width, causing it to consume two lines instead of one. Changing the width therefore also changes the height, which causes the layout to shift and, depending on where the pointer is, can cause rapid oscillation between the hovered and unhovered states. Prevent this by turning off white space wrapping.
.utility-nav-links > a > span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

A snippet to demonstrate:


document.querySelectorAll('.utility-nav-links > a > span').forEach(s => {
  s.style.setProperty('--intrinsicWidth', s.scrollWidth + 'px')
})
body {
  margin: 3em;
}

.utility-nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  gap: 1em;
}

.utility-nav-links > a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.utility-nav-links > a > img {
  background: #888;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.utility-nav-links > a > span {
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.utility-nav-links > a:hover > span {
  width: var(--intrinsicWidth);  /* value set in script */
}
<div class="utility-nav-links">
  <a>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
    <span>search</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/42">
    <span>info</span>
  </a>
  <a>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/44">
    <span>My Housing</span>
  </a>
</div>




Thank you so much. This is brilliant. I could have never thought about setting the span width dynamically. For someone starting out, could you give me any pointers on how to approach a solution like this or how I can improve more when it comes to creating animations?
